# Filling gaps between stone wall and floor to stop draught?

Tags: insulation, flooring

Just moved into an old 1900s tenement building (UK).  The bay window in the living room has a small bench built under it which has a freezing cold draught coming from the floor below.  What would be the best way to fill the gap to prevent cold air coming through?  Expanding foam?  Foam tubing for pipes?  The gap is too large to be filled with silicone/caulk, it varies between 0.5in - 1.5 inches.

One side is uneven stone wall and the other is wood. [image]

What's the industry standard way of sealing these gaps?

Comment: Can you post a picture please

Comment: Done, thank you!